# Android screen sizes support

Tags: java, android

I have carefully read the documentation in http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html and another related websites but I am still having doubts. Let me explain:

I have implemented dimens.xml for values, values-large and values-xlarge, so my Android application is nice when running on a tablet, for example. However, I have specified paddings, margins, text sizes and that stuff, but I don't know what to do with the images.

The problem is that images are small in comparison to the text sizes I put in dimens.xml. So, what should I do?

Should I create drawable-mdpi-large, drawable-hdpi-large, drawable-xhdpi-large, drawable-xxhdpi-large, drawable-mdpi-xlarge, and so on? (too much images for my APK)

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse, you want to create various drawable folder to set the images , so that as per the screen pixels the app automatically collect the exact image from drwable folder

I prefer this site ,it is more useful for you to set the images as per drawables..

> http://www.creativefreedom.co.uk/icon-designers-blog/android-app-icon-size-guide-4-0/

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. In that case, if I have mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, and three different screen sizes: normal, large, and xlarge, do I need 3x4 times the original image?

Comment: could you please answer my question? :)

Comment: not like tat.. basically for normal icons inside in your app..we  go for mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi... sizes are 48*48,72*72,96*96,144*144 respectievely, (if u want ldpi 36*36) .This iteration  can be vary for menu , actionbar icons.. for tat refer developers tutorial.... Let me back ,ur problm is solved r not..happy coding

Comment: Let me explain my question again: do I have to make images for different screen sizes in addition to the images for different screen densities?

Comment: i think you are undrstnding the concept wrongly..  density folders mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and  normal, large,xlarge, both of these pointng to same  idea.. Don't bothr this....In an app development we want to provide images as the sizes in density folders which i said above.. Tat is normal icons.. for actionbar it will different

Comment: no need of 3*4 times... want to manage nly mdpi, hpdi, xhdpi,xxhdpi

Comment: but appear small in large and xlarge screens since I am using bigger texts than in normal screens-

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to put your images in 4 folders like hdpi,ldpi,mdpi,xhdpi Once see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more info

Comment: That's not what I was asking for. I am asking if do I need to generate images for normal, large, and xlarge, and the four densities, 3x4 times the original image?

Comment: could you please answer my question? :
)

Comment: No you no need to generate all those images in different sizes, just put same images in different folders(drawable-mdpi-large, drawable-hdpi-large, drawable-xhdpi-large, drawable-xxhdpi-large, drawable-mdpi-xlarge, and so on) then android platform will knows which image it as to choose.