# Android - Multiple Screen support issue

Tags: android, css, xml, android-layout, layout

I am designing an Android Application that will support Tablets, but i am facing a small issue regarding the Multiple Screen Support.

Can anyone tell me, for the below layout design

```
 res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")

 res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size

 res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size

 res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size

 res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
```

we specify the below code in Manifest file.

```
<supports-screens

 android:largeScreens="true"

 android:normalScreens="true"

 android:smallScreens="true"

 android:resizeable="true"

 android:anyDensity="true"
 />
```

Now will the  code remains the same if the layouts are as below;

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)

res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)

res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

Is it compulsory to define   in Manifest file?? What if I don't define. Please help me.

Comment: Just Create one layout in layout folder. Use dimensions in other folders. Google it. It is much better way than to create different layouts. No need to alter manifest

Comment: In manifest you just put value that describe your application support regarding screen sizes. It has no connections with your layout files.

Comment: Thank you Rahul Gupta and Bozic Nebojsa for the help.

Comment: Check this [link Android screen sizes support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117805/android-screen-sizes-support/20118104#20118104)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Development Tutorial

Android powers hundreds of device types with several different screen sizes, ranging from small phones to large TV sets. Therefore, it’s important that you design your application to be compatible with all screen sizes so it’s available to as many users as possible.
But being compatible with different device types is not enough. Each screen size offers different possibilities and challenges for user interaction, so in order to truly satisfy and impress your users, your application must go beyond merely supporting multiple screens: it must optimize the user experience for each screen configuration.
 - See more at: http://fireandroids.blogspot.in/2014/01/developing-different-screen-sizes.html#sthash.tWtbmwLc.dpuf