# Font size of text

Tags: android, android-layout, font-size

I have created different `layouts (layout, layout-small, layout-normal, layout-large, layout-xlarge)` and for `values (values, values-ldpi, values-mdpi, values-nodpi, values-hdpi, values-xhdpi)`. I have one activity in my app to show text. I have scroll on text. And I set the values of text size in `values-mdpi`. But when I run my app on emulator `3.2"QVGA(ADP2)(320 x 480:mdpi)` scroll on text work. But when I run my app on emulator `5.1"WVGA(480 x 800:mdpi)` all text on half screen and the size of text is small. I think android picking layout depending upon size and text size depending upon `values-mdpi`. I want size of text big on large screen although they belong `mdpi`.

My whole app is in portrait mode. And also same case with ldpi and hdpi. Please provide general solution.

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Not getting much about text size.

Comment: See this, related to same Scenario...[CHECK THIS!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117805/android-screen-sizes-support/20118104#20118104)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create layout folders like `layout, layout-small, layout-large, layout-xlarge` then create values folders like `values, values-ldpi, values-mdpi, values-hdpi, values-xhdpi`. Then you can create values folder depending upon height or width and belongs to `ldpi` or `mdpi` i.e `values-w360dp-mdpi or values-h600dp-mdpi`. Then android automatically picks layout depending upon screen size and values on depending height or width.

Answer (score 2):

Create folder like `values-mdpi` , `values-w360dp-mdpi` in res folder.

create dimens.xml on both folder.

and paste it below code in values-mdpi dimens.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <resources>
           <dimen name="textsize">14sp</dimen>

       </resources>
```

and paste it below code in values-w360dp-mdpi dimens.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <resources>
           <dimen name="textsize">18sp</dimen>
       </resources>
```

then apply text size on your activity

```
android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
```

Comment: Can you explain this?

Comment: w360 mean width atleast 360dp?

Answer (score 2):

you are using only portrait version, if you are using same structure of design for all devices **you don't need to add four different layout** for each pixel density.

create android values folders that supports different screen sizes.

[image]

Here first folder for  7inch android devices that have ANDROID version 3.1 or less. second one is for 7inch devices that have android version greater than 3.1. 
naming convention sw600 means smallest width of 600. so this folder works for width size 600 to 720. So create **values-sw480dp** and **values-sw320** add values to dimens.xml file.

Android runtime automatically picks values from appropriate folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:resizeable="true"
                  android:smallScreens="true"/>
```

Comment: Can you provide sources?

Answer (score 1):

Just instead your`values (values, values-ldpi, values-mdpi, values-nodpi, values-hdpi, values-xhdpi)`, 
which are specifying the text font sizes for each density.

Use text size specification based on screen size, like this:`values (values, values-small, values-normal, values-large, values-xlarge)`

Alternatively to obtain better results for various devices you can combine density with screen size, like this:`values-normal-mdpi`

That's all

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

STEP : 1
   first in   `res` folder =>  values => dimensions.xml=> create  `dimensions.xml`  file to  `values folder`  in that create like below code depending on textsize

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <resources>
           <dimen name="textsize">8sp</dimen>
           <dimen name="text">10sp</dimen>
           <dimen name="comments">7sp</dimen>
       </resources>
```

STEP : 2
   in java file write this line

```
      TextView textviewtwo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sponsertwo_txt);
textviewtwo.setText("brought to you by");    
textviewtwo.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
  getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize));
      // in place of textsize use text and comments what ever we want depending on size. use like text size                  adjust automatically in all devices
```

Comment: I want to do this by using layout and values. How i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to create all these layout directories to handle text size. Just stick with the normal one (layout) and create different values directories with different text size for each resolution you want to support. so you have to add text size in other values directories.

At run-time Android will pick the correct text size.

Comment: you are not understanding. Above 2 devices have different sizes but belong to mdpi. So text size from values-mdpi is using by above 2. But the device 3.2" having normal size screen so text looking good and 5.1" having large screen. So text size very small.

Comment: Try to use another values directory (values-large)

Comment: But I dont know to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, it works based on screen size:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int displayWidth = display.getWidth();

yourTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,(float)(displayWidth * 6/100));
```