# How to design an android app for 3.5 inches and 3.7inch screen?

Tags: android

I have developed my app in 3.7 inch galaxy S2 with Drawable/hdpi (480x720px) now  I want to design it for Micromax A54 with 3.5 inch screen 320x480px

Both are Normal screen sizes but their densities are different I have referred these tutorials

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8dGQEN9sRs, 
  http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range,
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources,
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch,
- [Supporting multiple screen size - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124079/supporting-multiple-screen-size-android)

but still I am stuck is there any other way of doing like direct through coding or i am going wrong please help me?

Comment: show your Android layout XML please

Comment: Create layouts depending upon height or width on device. They belong to same density then this problem solved.

Comment: See this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21274692/font-size-of-text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take one xml only and set my layout like in java class like this

```
int widthPixels,density,widthDp,scaleFactor ;
density= getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;

  widthPixels = metrics.widthPixels;
  scaleFactor = metrics.density;
  widthDp = widthPixels / scaleFactor;
```

now i have all density width height now i set in my xml like

```
 if(widthDp==600)
                {
                    imageWidth = 45;
                    imgHeight = 45;
                    margin = 11;
                }
                else if (widthDp==720)
                {

                }
                else if(density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH)
                {
                    imageWidth = 60;
                    imgHeight = 60;
                    margin = 17;
                }
                else if(density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW)
                {
                    imageWidth = 30;
                    imgHeight = 30;
                    margin = 9;
                }
                else if(density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM)
                {
                    imageWidth = 40;
                    imgHeight = 40;
                    margin = 10;
                }
                else
                {
                    imageWidth = 60;
                    imgHeight = 60;
                    margin = 13;
                }
```

u can also set all variable which u want to set or take in your xml here i only ser height,width and margin
**Best of luck dude**

Comment: Hey Bhanu. is it wright way of doing coz i haven't got any kind of such technique on developers site and video tutorials both..

Comment: abhi developers make his/her own technique other wise it will be a just copy paste i make this my own and set 12 different layouts with this just try dude its very easy and  developers site just mention how u will got density of any mob device ohk and i apply that tech in this like my code :)
new ideas is always be a new technique dude just do it :)

Comment: if u take many layout then it will be waste of code just make diff drawable folder and take diff diff images if u use images in your app then only i.e android take automatically diff images according to size of device

Comment: I have inserted 320x480 px images for 3.5 inch Micromax a54 but these images are not picked up by my device. both the screens comes under normal screen sizes?

Comment: abhi u have to make diff diff drawable for it dude and just set that in java class with like height and width, margin

Comment: like drawable-hdpi, drawable-large, drawable-ldpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xlarge-mdpi and so on  drawable-sw600dp,drawable-sw720dp and put all images in their folder and then set all images in java code

Comment: in  oncreate method only after set layout and findviewbyid of all view

Comment: Which variable is this metrics?

Comment: Hey Bhanu plzzzz reply

Comment: private DisplayMetrics metrics;
metrics = new DisplayMetrics();

Comment: and what are these variables imageWidth etc?

Comment: private int imageWidth,imgHeight,margin;

Comment: ohk now u declare dude just chill

Comment: dear what if i need to adjust particular images width and height?

Comment: u can only set imageview width and height dude just take that reference(findviewbuid) and use but i think dont take it hardcode just use diff size of images

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49035/discussion-between-bhanu-sharma-and-abhi)